# Cartesian Product containment implies individual contaiment

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following problem originates from Munkres "Topology a First Course" page 14 Question 2k. 
Given sets $A,B,C,D$ if $A \times B \subset C \times D$ does that necessarily imply that $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$?

My intuitive belief is yes, since  $A \times B \subset C \times D$ literally means for every tuple $(a,b)$ where $a \in A, b\in B$ there exists a tuple $(c,d)$ where $c \in C, d \in D$ and $a = c, b = d$. But I grow suspicious because Munkres asks three questions about this, (which I thought was trivial) and so perhaps I have the wrong impression. Does $A,B,C,D$ being non-empty somehow make this fact true, and the way I have stated it is false? Or is he just playing games with the reader's intuition.

Comment: Suppose $A=\emptyset$.  Then $A\times B = \emptyset \subset C\times D$ regardless of the relationship between $B$ and $D$.

Comment: ahhh... you can't refer to an "empty element" so that's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are non empty sets then your intuition is correct.

If any one the sets $A$ and $B$ is empty set then it need not be true.